# maxstep Gaussian keywords

Tags: gaussian, geometry-optimization

I'm running a Berny optimization and I need to include the keyword `maxstep=1`.

Observing the output, in the convergence summary table I can see that the `Max Displacement` value does not equal the one I set, but it is greather.
I surfed online and I found that I need to add the `NoTrust` keyword, but I still don't understand it.

Can anyone explain it?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if over the last  6 months you figured out the answer? Please write a self-answer if you did! Otherwise, are you still actively needing an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Gaussian manual is still obscure to me, and anywhere else I was not able to find the answer. So I'm not able to self-respond to the question. @NikeDattani

Comment: How about now, after another 6 months? Are you still working on this?

Comment: Answered on Chem SE: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/136403/41556